# I have a transformer core - need help with winding/calculation

Tags: transformer

I have a microwave oven transformer which I had damaged in the process of removing the high-voltage secondary. I will be using this for spot welding 18650 cells. I have all the required figures.

[image]

I wish to know if changing the wire gauge would affect the current output in the secondary; I need the maximum current output.

As far as I understand, the heat loss and resistance depends on the primary winding gauge and the current draw in the secondary depends on the width of the cemetery core and the gauge of the secondary winding, correct?

With that said, 22AWG would be a little less thereby creating more heat in the primary but would help adding more turns on the secondary thereby increasing current draw.

[Link to MOT dimensions](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/transformer-primary-winding-wire-gauge-difference.133462/#post-1109796)

Comment: 1 T flux density?! That's possible with silicon steel, but even there it'd typically pretty close to saturation

Comment: the excel sheet was take from here http://ludens.cl/Electron/trafos/trafos.html

Comment: The transformer did not have anything on the spec to check the T Flux so that was the default value. Would it possible to determine the flux ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller 1T is far below saturation. George: the primary remains as is, no matter what you change on secondary winding.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I have something like 0.3 T in my head for saturation of powder cores, and something like 1.5 T for high-quality steel cores, so that's where my remark comes from

Comment: so what happens with the gauge of the primary. If possible what difference would make if it is 22AWG or 16AWG. Not very good at the electrical terms so i appreciate a more simple answer or an explanation.

Comment: I've linked the dimensions of the MOT in another webpage. https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/transformer-primary-winding-wire-gauge-difference.133462/#post-1109796

Comment: @MarcusMüller You will hardly buy a toroid transformer from China that has a flux density less than 1.9T. I do buy UI transformers from local shop, he builds them around 1.2 to 1.4T. I had problems running those toroidal transformers on industrial distribution network: once you switch on, the fuse blows even if it is 20x rated, this is saturation.  And I had learned that quality build transformer can be cheaper than buying from web (weight), it just takes time to find a man.

Comment: hmmm I could see one of my existing transformers secondary wave form to be a little distorted ? does that mean the core is saturating and dumb it ?

Comment: My comment is off topic regarding transformers, but if you're spot welding tabs on batteries, you can do this with a capacitive discharge spot welder. Any cheapo DC power supply with current limiting will recharge the cap bank.

Answer (score 0):

For the given core size, you have the nominal power. Compute the primary winding turns with respect on required flux density. The primary cross section is defined with primary nominal current. For secondary compute the the turns using ratio formula Ns/Np=Vs/Vp. Use secondary wire thickness with respect of nominal secondary current and/or check that the window is completely filled.

Comment: hmmm compute  ???? Could you suggest a primary wire gauge and number of turns based on the pics attached in my post, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: At the time of the answer, there were no pics, just "I have damaged the secondary..." . Well you scarped all, you have a bare core. Do you have a bobin where you will put the winding? You should change your question in : I have a core...how can I calculate a transformer.

Comment: Sorry if this thread was leading. I've change the heading now. Was the pics helpful to determine the wire gauge and the number of windings.

Comment: @George Is your primary winding still alive? Do you have a bobin? If not how do you plan to wind the transformer? Do you have insulation material?

Comment: I have the damaged coil so with that size and comparing with the transformer core i've made a jig to wind the coil. I will be using this as a insulator http://www.ebay.com/itm/322052070894?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT and the wire http://www.ebay.com/itm/251135583230?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: @George That's a pit. The easiest solution is to somehow estimate or count Nr of turns of  damaged primary and redo it. The other option is to find a suitable calculator on the web. This is what I have found: http://www.microformer.org/make-your-microformer/ . Then the secondary is just trivial, you have Nrof turns and then you put such wire that fills the window.